# Edittext selection menu and soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection, android-softkeyboard

In my activity, I have a multiline `EditText` that takes a big space on the screen. When I click on it, I enter the edit mode and the soft keyboard shows up. So far so good

Now I want to select the text. So I long press on it, and the selection handles appear. The problem is that when I select multiple lines, the whole layout of the activity will be pushed up to be able to see the selection above the keyboard. But it also pushes up the selection menu that allows to interact with the selection (like Copy, Search, etc.), so the selection is useless!

So best solution would be to make sure the menu stays visible, alternative solution would be to hide the keyboard when selection happens so that nothing is being pushed up.!

As you can see on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tOcI.png), the menu is almost gone because the selection is right on top of the keyboard, but without the keyboard it should appear just fine

Comment: I got the same question as yours. Did you find any solution?